# Вопрос по INSER INTO параметризированным запросам в C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Вот у меня есть такой код:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conect))
    {
    con.Open();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO C#Table VALUES(@param1 ,@param2 ,@param3 ,@param4 ,@param5 ,@param6 ,@param7)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "01-02-2015";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "фывфыв";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "фывфыфывыфвв";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "фыпа";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "фпавп";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param6", SqlDbType.Decimal, 13).Value = 23525.533;
    cmd.Parameters["@param6"].Precision = 13;
    cmd.Parameters["@param6"].Scale = 2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param7", SqlDbType.Decimal, 13).Value = 23535.35235;
    cmd.Parameters["@param7"].Precision = 13;
    cmd.Parameters["@param7"].Scale = 2;
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    }
```

Если я хочу сразу несколько строк добавить, как это сделать? Что придется что ли добавлять строку и делать что то типа:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO C#Table VALUES(@param1 ,@param2 ,@param3 ,@param4 ,@param5 ,@param6 ,@param7), (@param8 ,@param9 ,@param10 ,@param11 ,@param12 ,@param13 ,@param14)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить несколько строк, можно вынести в отдельный метод и вызывать в цикле или если известно какое количество строк нужно добавлять, то

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9);
```

Пример вызова отдельного метода:

```
 public void Data()
 {
     foreach(Parameter par in pars)
     {
         InsertRow(par);
     }
 }


 public void InsertRow(входящие данные)
 {
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conect))
     {
        // Код добавления
     }
 }
```